# How can I print 86 in new line like hello world?

Tags: python, string, multiplication

```
Var1 = "54"
Var2 = "32"
Print(2 * "hello world\n")
Print(2 * str(int(var1)+int(var2)))
```

Comment: You don't have to use \n. print automatically adds that.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want the output to be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  Your question is missing some key information — notably the desired output.  You should ask a question in the body; asking a question in the title alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Pay attention to case. You define `Var1` then try to use `var1`. `Print` isn't a builtin function but `print` is. Also, when posting include the python traceback error message and what you want the output to look like. Right now you get `Hello World` twice on two lines with an empty line afterwards. Did you want that?

Comment: I want my output to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate a newline to the string before multiplying by 2.

```
print(2 * (str(int(var1) + int(var2)) + "\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

first to sum 2 integers you should not put them between double quotes or single quotes like you did, in that case it will sum up as strings and results in ***'54' + '32' = 5432*** and for the new line, **print** already do it for you.

```
x = 54
y = 32

print(x+y)
```

ouput

```
86
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I did not understand what you want the first time, now I got it, try this:

```
x = 54
y = 32
z = x + y
print(str(z)+'\n'+str(z))
```

output

```
86
86
```

upvote and checkmark :-)

Answer (score 0):

python's print command will always print on a new line when it is invoked, but since you are using the "2 * value" you are not actually invoking the print twice, youre telling print to print 2 versions of the value.

With that, you can add a new line character after your 86 to make it show on 2 lines as shown below.

Also it's preferential, but it makes things a lot easier to debug when you separate large actions out.
Casting strings to ints, adding the ints together, and printing all in one line is a lot to digest when debugging and makes it more difficult to understand what exactly went wrong. It adds a few lines but it makes everything much more readable. At the very least, you could move the action to it's own function, especially if you will be calling it many times.

```
var1="54"
var2="32"

print(2 * "hello world\n")

int1 = int(var1)
int2 = int(var2)
added = int1 + int2
var_str = "%s\n"%(added)
print(2 * var_str)
```